# use .hasClass() in jquery with if clause

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Is it valid to use an if clause with .hasClass()?

Example:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("class")){
    this will happen
}
```

Or

```
if ($(this).hasClass("class") == true){
    this will happen
}
```

Comment: If only there was some way to find out...

Comment: `..hasClass()` is an expression that evaluates to a useful value: *any* expression can be used in an `if`-statement, with the appropriate operators (if/as needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is valid to use an `if` statement with any expression. The `if` statement is a control flow statement that either jumps over the immediate block (or single statement) or executes it, depending on the value of the expression inside the statement. Any value will be coerced to Boolean using standard coercion rules.

The `==` comparison operator evaluates to a Boolean that's `true` if both both operands are equal (using [this algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)), and `false` otherwise. A comparison of any value to `true` is redundant, since if it is `true`, or is convertible to `true`, the expression would also be `true`, and will be `false` for any other value

In the case of `.hasClass()`, the return value is already a Boolean so no coercion is required.

So, Yes it's valid, there's no difference between the statements, and you can (and should) use the first.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [**source**](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.hasClass) itself of [**hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/), we can see that only a *boolean* can be returned

```
function (selector) {
    var className = " " + selector + " ",
        i = 0,
        l = this.length;
    for (; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i].nodeType === 1 && (" " + this[i].className + " ").replace(rclass, " ").indexOf(className) >= 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Therefore, checking without comparing is valid

```
if ($(this).hasClass("class")){
```